# VSCode is activating conda base environment despite .condarc having auto_activate_base:false set

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, conda

Every time I open a shell in VS Code within a python project for which I want to use a conda environment, VS Code activates the base conda environment, then activates the `python.pythonPath` environment. I want VS Code to just activate the conda environment I am pointing to in the `python.pythonPath` setting.

e.g.

In my workspace settings I have set:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/Users/me@home.com/opt/anaconda3/envs/pytorch/bin/python"
```

Each time I open a new shell in the workspace I get this output (before running any manual commands):

```
source /Users/me@home.com/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
conda activate pytorch
15:51:44 with me@home.com in pytorch on  master 
❯ source /Users/me@home.com/opt/anaconda3/bin/activate
(base) 15:51:44 with me@home.com in pytorch on  master 
❯ conda activate pytorch
(pytorch) 15:51:44 with me@home.com in pytorch on  master 
❯
```

In my `~/.condarc` I also have `auto_activate_base: false` set so I am confused why VS Code is activating the base environment in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Received an answer from opening up an issue in microsoft/vscode-python [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/12379):

> the extension sends that. It's because we have noticed some conda versions that the activation doesn't work unless base is activated first.